# Can I get my directory name list from Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Can I get my directory namelist from wolfram Cloud?

```
dir = CloudDirectory[]

(*
    CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-3bacf318-4194-4e57-969f-fa786e54ab7d
]
*)

dirOld = FileNameJoin[{dir, "Old"}]

(*
    CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-3bacf318-4194-4e57-969f-fa786e54ab7d
/Old]
*)

DirectoryQ@dirOld

(*
    True
*)

FileNames["*", dirOld, \[Infinity]]

(*
    {}
*)
```

I mean the word namelist[Here is MyPackages,Old,Project,...], not uuidlist which can be obtain by `CloudObjects[]`
[image]

Comment: Please provide a notebook snippet showing that there actually are subdirectories under directory Old.

Comment: Perhaps try `CloudEvaluate[FileNames[...]]` or `CloudObjectInformation[CloudObjects[dirOld], "Name"]`.

Comment: @ilian Thanks, you can make this as an answer.  `names = CloudObjectInformation[CloudObjects[""]];
#[[1, "Name"]] & /@ Select[names, #[[1, "FileType"]] == Directory &]`

Answer (score 1):

```
CloudObjects["cloud directory"]
```

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more detailed? Thank you!